# how can I change cpanel default page to index.php / index.html

Tags: apache, cpanel, web-hosting

I have created a new domain and uploaded index.html to public directory. but it isnt displaying and cpanel default page is displaying instead. how can I change the same??

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://serverfault.com/questions/229956/how-can-i-disable-cpanel-difault-page).

Answer (score 2):

Try putting this in the .htaccess file in your root web directory:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is down to permissions. Try CHMODing your files to 755.